# Vuejs pagination save currentPage

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I'm using a `<b-table>` with pagination enabled.

```
<b-pagination v-model="currentPage"
    :total-rows="rows"
    :per-page="perPage"
    align="center"
    first-number
    last-number
    @change="turnOffEdit"
    @input="handlePageClick"></b-pagination>
```

When I am on page 3 for example and load the details of an element and then go back to the page with the b-table, the `currentPage` is reset to 1.
I want to stay on the page I was last at (in this example page 3) when I return to the page with the b-table.

I've already tried the following:

```
currentPage: number = 1;

mounted() {
    this.id = this._uid;
    if (this.form) {
        this.formElement = document.querySelector(this.form);
        this.formElement.addEventListener('submit', this.update);
        this.formElement.addEventListener('reset', this.reset);

        if (this.autosubmit) {
            this.formElement.addEventListener('change', this.update);
        }
    }

    console.log("*** mounted");
    this.LoadFiltersFromSessionStorage();
    console.log("*** currentPage: " + this.currentPage)

    Vue.prototype.$refresh = this.refresh;
}

LoadFiltersFromSessionStorage() {
    // ...
    let currentPageKey = Object.keys(sessionStorage).filter(f => f.endsWith("currentPage"));
    currentPageKey = currentPageKey[0].replace(this.filterPrefix, '');
    console.log("******************** " + sessionStorage[currentPageKey])
    this.currentPage = (+sessionStorage[currentPageKey] ? +sessionStorage[currentPageKey] : 1);
    console.log("load currentPage: " + this.currentPage);
}

handlePageClick() {
    sessionStorage[this.filterPrefix + "currentPage"] = JSON.stringify(this.currentPage);
}
```

My thoughts were the following:
When clicking on a page in the pagination control, the currentPage is saved to the session storage.
When coming back to the page and the component is created again, the currentPage should get loaded from the session storage and thus change to the page that the user had been on before.

But I have a problem:

- In the `mounted()`, the currentPage can not be loaded, it's always `undefined`, even though the session storage does have the key

[image]

the console.log are this:

> *** mounted
> ******************** undefined
> load currentPage: 1
> *** currentPage: 1

How can I achieve the behavior, that the currentPage is correctly loaded fromthe session storage and the pagination is loading the page of the currentPage from the session storage?

We're using this vue version:

- "vue": "^2.6.14",

so I don't have the `page-click` event available.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tried passing dynamic prop current-page to b-table?
<b-table :current-page="currentPage"></b-table>

Comment: Did you check the output of `Object.keys(window.sessionStorage)` and whether `[this.filterPrefix + "currentPage"]` is there ?

Comment: @PavanJ: yes on the b-table I have the :current-page set

Comment: @IVOGELOV yes the Key [this.filterPrefix + "currentPage"] is available when returning to the previous page

Comment: Well, if the given Key exists - then why are not you using it to access the session storage but instead removing the prefix `this.filterPrefix` ? Changing the key in this way will **definitely** give you an `undefined` result.

Comment: @IVOGELOV omg... you're right I don't know why I did that *facepalm* now the data is loaded correctly! but unfortunately, the wrong page number in the pagination is highlighted (still page 1 instead of f.e. page 3). Do I have to refresh it somehow?

Comment: If you set `currentPage` to the proper value - then this value should propagate through the `v-model` of `b-pagination`.